# Is there a way to return error cause entity?

Tags: java, android, android-room

When the insert or update returns error it returns a long of (-1), is there anyway to return the error entity when inserting same id?

I'm currently using this code :

```java
// Inserting new product
long id = database.productDAO().insert(product);
// Product already exists
if (id == -1) {
    Product existingProduct = database.productDAO().select(product.getId());
    existingProduct.setInventory(product.getInventory());
    if (count > existingProduct.getAllowedMax())
        existingProduct.setAllowedMax(count);

    database.productDAO().update(existingProduct);
}

@Dao
public interface ProductDAO {
    /**
     * @return all of products
     */
    @Query("SELECT * FROM product")
    List<Product> select();

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    List<Long> insert(Product... products);

    @Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    void update(Product... products);
}
```

I want to be some way so I can directly find the error entity and make changes so I can get rid of a select query and save some resource, like this :

```java
 Product existingProduct = database.productDAO().insert(product);
// Product already exists
if (existingProduct != null){
    existingProduct.setInventory(product.getInventory());
    if (count > existingProduct.getAllowedMax())
        existingProduct.setAllowedMax(count);

    database.productDAO().update(existingProduct);}
```

Comment: You need to update the insert method of your DAO .. you need to add it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
productDAO().insert method should return the inserted product, and from there you can get the product id.

public Product insert(Product ObjectToAdd){

{ 
   if (DuplicateId){ // use a flag or a try/catch block to know if there is a record with given id already.

    return null // or set the id to -1 or some default value :) ObjectToAdd.setId(-1)
   }

  return ObjectToAdd
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this does the same thing as my code I'm looking for a way to make Room do the stuff in sql and get rid of **unwanted** select query.

Comment: Anyway, a select operation is needed to receive data for product fields (inventory, allowedMax).

Answer (score 0):

Remove `OnConflictStrategy` from the queries. this causes to throw the exception so you can handle it as you wanted.

```
@Insert
List<Long> insert(Product... products);
```

Now when you invoke the above method, if room encounters any error at runtime it throws an Exception, you can catch and provide custom error handling logic

```
try {
    long id = database.productDAO().insert(product);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // handle it here
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I'm looking for the entity that threw the exception, for example if id 1 is not unique retrieve the id 1 automatically from room and I don't want to use a select query

Comment: Not possible at the moment